# Defining functions in Python 3 and Parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this tutorial that does this

```
c = (x, y)

def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
     do something
     return
```

and then calls `addVectors` with:

```
addVector((a, b), c)
```

but python 3 just gives me a syntax error on the parenthesis around `(angle1, lenght1)`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be possible in Python 2, but was removed in Python 3 via [PEP-3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

The solution is to unpack the argument inside the function:

```
def addVectors(angle1_length1, angle2_length2):
    angle_1, length1 = angle1_length1
    angle_2, length2 = angle2_length2
    do something
    return
```

Comment: superb, i was not able to find this for 2 hours

Comment: @user1933393, yeah it's particularly tough to find the right search terms for a question like this :)

Answer (score 3):

From [what's new in Python3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> [**PEP 3113**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113): Tuple parameter unpacking removed. You can no longer write `def foo(a,
>   (b, c))`: .... Use `def foo(a, b_c): b, c = b_c` instead.